# Why does adding a border or padding to an element stop border collapsing?

Tags: html, css

I've followed this post - ( [Why is adding or removing a border changing the way margins work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154703/why-is-adding-or-removing-a-border-changing-the-way-margins-work) ) but I can't see anywhere in the specifications about border or padding being mentioned.

Let's say I have a two divs in question, the top div is my header and the div bellow is my nav which contains a paragraph "meee". The  paragraph's(inside nav) margin will be greater than the top divs margin so the parent element(div) will get pushed down. This isn't the result I desire, I would like to move the paragraph element down inside of its parent div. One way to accomplish this is if I add a border to the div, this allows me to move the bottom paragraph down inside the div.

But as my question suggests, why does adding a border or padding stop margin collapsing?

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Adam's page 4</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <p> Meeee </p>
    </div>

    <div class="side">

        <p> Hello</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    </div>

   <div class="footer">
   </div>
   </div>

.header{

  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* margin-bottom: 100px; */

}

.nav{

  /* margin-top: 120px; */
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  /*border: 1px solid red; */

}

.nav p{
    
    background-color: peru;
   }
```

(Question is, ***why*** does adding a border or some padding prevent border collapsing not ***how*** to prevent border collapsing. Other question just asks and solves the problem)

[image]

Comment: Please share a minimal code example, from the text I don't understand what you need.

Comment: *no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them*

Comment: but why does adding a padding or border prevent collapsing?